# General inverse for a symmetric matrix of the form $\mathbf A_n = \left(a_{\min(i,j)}b_{\max(i,j)}\right)$

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

I am looking for a general inverse formula for a symmetric matrix of the form
$$ \mathbf A_n = \left(a_{\min(i,j)}b_{\max(i,j)}\right) = \pmatrix{ a_1b_1 & a_1b_2 & a_1b_3 & \cdots & a_1b_n \\
a_1b_2 & a_2b_2 & a_2b_3 & \cdots & a_2b_n \\
\vdots &    & \ddots  &        & \vdots \\
a_1b_n & a_2b_n &   &        & a_nb_n} $$
where $a_i,b_i $ are real numbers.  Empirically I can see that $ \mathbf A_n^{-1} $ is tridiagonal so I suspect it has previously been studied.  For example we have
$$ \mathbf A_5 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \frac{a_2}{a_1 a_2 b_1-a_1^2 b_2} & \frac{1}{a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1} & \frac{a_1 b_3-a_3 b_1}{\left(a_2 b_1-a_1 b_2\right) \left(a_2 b_3-a_3 b_2\right)} & \frac{1}{a_2 b_3-a_3 b_2} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{a_2 b_3-a_3 b_2} & \frac{a_2 b_4-a_4 b_2}{\left(a_3 b_2-a_2 b_3\right) \left(a_3 b_4-a_4 b_3\right)} & \frac{1}{a_3 b_4-a_4 b_3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{a_3 b_4-a_4 b_3} & \frac{a_3 b_5-a_5 b_3}{\left(a_4 b_3-a_3 b_4\right) \left(a_4 b_5-a_5 b_4\right)} & \frac{1}{a_4 b_5-a_5 b_4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{a_4 b_5-a_5 b_4} & \frac{b_4}{a_5 b_4 b_5-a_4 b_5^2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which seems to be based on a bunch of 2x2 determinants...

Any help appreciated, thank you!

p.

Comment: Your $\mathbf{A}_n$ is called a "матрица Грина" (Greene matrix?) in §2.11 of [В. В. Прасолов, *Задачи и теоремы линейной алгебры*, 2nd edition, Издательство МЦНМО 2016](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=96E8D5E39736534C65D0CC994FE417E5). That source gives a formula for its minors, which in particular includes the entries of its adjugate and thus leads to formulas for its inverse as well. Unfortunately, the 2nd edition has not (to my knowledge) been translated into English.

Comment: Aha, apparently it's "Green's matrix" in English (see [McDonald, J. J., Nabben, R., Neumann, M., Scheider, H., & Tsatsomeros, M. J. (1998). *Inverse tridiagonal Z-Martices*. Linear and Multilinear Algebra, **45**(1), 75–97](https://sci-hub.se/10.1080/03081089808818578)).

Comment: Going further back in history: [F. R. Gantmacher, M. G. Krein, *Oscillation Matrices and Kernels and Small Vibrations of Mechanical Systems*, AMS, 2002](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=C90BEDB7953F1BFDEAB26A22E9175783) (the book was first published in 1960; this is a 3rd edition) calls $\mathbf{A}_n$ a "single-pair matrix" in §II.3, Example 5.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after researching inversion of symmetric tridiagonal matrices, it appears that $ \mathbf A$ is known as a "*matrice factorisable*" with tridiagonal inverse
$$
 \mathbf A^{-1} =
\pmatrix{ \alpha_1 & \beta_1 & & \\
\beta_1 & \alpha_2 & \beta_2 & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \\
& & \beta_{n-1} & \alpha_n }
$$
where:
$$
\alpha_1 = - \frac{a_2}{a_1 u_{1,2}},
\alpha_i = \frac{u_{i-1,i+1}}{u_{i-1,i}u_{i,i+1}},
\alpha_n = -\frac{b_{n-1}}{b_n u_{n-1,n}},
\beta_i = \frac{1}{u_{i,i+1}},
u_{i,j} = a_i b_j (v_j - v_i),
v_i = \frac{b_i}{a_i}
$$
subject to a's and b's being nonzero and $v_i \neq v_{i+1}$.

There is also an interesting factorization of the form $\mathbf A = \mathbf {DL}^T\boldsymbol\Lambda\mathbf{LD}$ where $\mathbf D$ is diagonal, $\mathbf L$ is lower triangular, and $\boldsymbol\Lambda$ is superdiagonal together with one last diagonal coefficient.  I hope this helps anyone encountering a similar type of matrix!

p.

Reference: J. BARANGER, M. DUC-JACQUET, "Matrices tridiagonales symétriques et matrices factorisables". In: *Revue française d’informatique et de recherche opérationnelle*, vol. 5, no R3 (1971), pp. 61-66.

Comment: Your original expression for the inverse looks to me a lot more elegant. It would be good to have an explanation of why the denominators are connected with $a\wedge b$ in the way that they are!

Comment: the connection with 2x2 determinants appears here:  https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~raf.vandebril/homepage/publications/phd/node33.html